Weighted percentages?
it's been a while since I have been working formulas and sheets and I can't get my brain to function.
I have two percentages: A) 120% and B) 179%, of which A) is weighted with 65% and B) is weighted 35%. I need to get the overall percentage of A) and B) taking the weighted percentages into account, meaning percentage A) is "worth" more with 65% and B) weigh only 35% into the overall percentage of these two.
How do I put this in a formula in sheets?

=(120*65+179*35)/(65+35) or =SUMPRODUCT({120,179},{65,35})/SUM(65,35) more universal

Amazing thank you!


You may try:
=average.weighted(A3:B3,A2:B2)


